# How to create a border for every page in PDF generation using FOP (xsl and ftl)?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am generating pdf using FOP, and I want to include border for every page in pdf. I am using XSLT 2.0.

**Is there any way or any attribute or any tags to create a border for every page in XSL?**

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `border` attribute to the `fo:region-*` elements (and `padding` too, if needed).

---

Note that, strictly speaking, this is ***not*** allowed by the [XSL recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_region-body):

> The values of the **padding** and **border-width** traits must be "0".

and the standard behaviour of FOP would be to end with a validation error:

```
SEVERE: Exception javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: 
org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Border and padding for fo:region-body 
"xsl-region-body" should be '0' (See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values
are allowed if relaxed validation is enabled.  (See position ...)
```

However, as this is after all a common use case and other formatters allow this too, you can run FOP with **relaxed validation** and get the desired output:

- adding the option `-r` if you are running FOP from the command line
- using the `FopFactoryBuilder.setStrictFOValidation()` method in the Java code

You still get a warning about the non-standard behaviour, but the processing continues normally:

```
WARNING: Border and padding for fo:region-body "xsl-region-body" should be '0' 
(See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values are allowed if relaxed validation
is enabled.  (See position ...)
```